# Migrating from external source to AD

Tags: active-directory

I'm not even sure where to start so any info would be helpful.

My organization uses AD for authentication... and that's about it. All users are stored in a single OU and then under a group OU when appropriate and all under one domain. We don't use AD to track/store phone numbers, ext., dept., directors, etc. However, we have started using OTRS as our ticketing system and if you're familiar with it, it integrates nicely with AD to provide the ticket requester's info such as phone, ext., email, etc. Well, we keep all of that information in a third party system. Specifically, a product called inteli-desk.

I'm a dba guy not an AD guy (just enough to cause damage) so my question is: Is there a way/tool or something to migrate the information from the SQL Server db that inteli-desk uses and populate it in AD?

Comment: You could do this yourself with powershell, if you're comfortable using smo  and the powershell ad commandlets.

Comment: +1 on powershell. I had a related situation a while ago. I had to get ~400 Users information, which was provided in different formats from different systems, into a brand new 2012R2 AD. I started by setting up an excel sheet, using data import tools and excel conditions and formulas to tidy it up and exported as CSV. With the AD-cmdlets provided by powershell you will have no trouble importing it afterwards. If needed, I can provide an answer with sample data and commands.

Comment: Patrick examples would be greatly appreciated. I'm just not really familiar AD cmdlets. I can dump the info from the third party db tables into excel as a csv pretty easy but not exactly how to use the cmdlets to push it into AD.

Comment: Powershell "speaks" CSV, the hardest part will be mapping the data from the SQL to the appropriate attributes in Active Directory.

Comment: There's just an LDAP directory underneath, so you shouldn't find it too difficult to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell "speaks" CSV, the hardest part will be mapping the data from the SQL to the appropriate attributes in Active Directory. [Check out this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ca04cdce-472a-4d29-a3c5-91285dc2dcd8/importcsv-to-update-active-directory-users) Make sure you read the comments, the script listed there has a typo.

Depending on the version of AD & your powershell version some of this may already be done for you.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be a great starting point and will hopefully work.